# Weakening and Contraction

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Wikipedia has an article on [structural rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rule) that states the following:

- Weakening is a structural rule where the hypotheses or conclusion of a sequent may be extended with additional members.
- Contraction is a rule where two equal (or unifiable) members on the same side of a sequent may be replaced by a single member (or common instance).

However, I can't seem to get the terms yet. There are even these symbols ("⊢") that looks like a T turned counterclockwise.

In simple terms, what are weakening and contraction? Can they even be described without the symbol that looks like a T turned counterclockwise?

Comment: The "T turned clockwise" means that whatever is on the right of that symbol *can be proven* using whatever is on the left of it.

Comment: @5xum Great! The symbols look readable now. Are the tags on my question correct? :-D

Comment: Are you aware that you are taling about Sequent calculus ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) not the more well known  Natural deduction ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction ) in natural deduction the structural rules are assumed "build in in the rules" the left rules are true whatever  the right rules RW is or introduction , Rc is removing of duplicates. Sequent calculus is rather advanced, better start with natural deduction (but you will learn some bad habids on the way, so maybe it is no such good idea) ,

Comment: @Willemien Initially I had no idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In *sequent calculus*, **Weakening** (or *Thinning*) and **Contraction** are the so-called *structural rules* of inference.

**Weakening** rule introduces an extra formula $D$ in the antecedent: :

> $$\frac{\Gamma\vdash \Delta}{D,\Gamma\vdash \Delta} \text {LW}$$

or in the succedent :

> $$\frac{\Gamma\vdash \Delta}{\Gamma\vdash \Delta,D} \text {RW}$$

of the *sequent* $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$, where $\Gamma, \Delta$ are sets of formulae.

The "meaning" of the rule is the following :

> > if we have a *derivation* of the sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$, we can "add" a formula $D$ to the set of assumptions .

**Contraction** rule is :

> $$\frac{D,D,\Gamma\vdash \Delta}{D,\Gamma\vdash \Delta} \text {LC}$$

and :

> $$\frac{\Gamma\vdash \Delta,D,D}{\Gamma\vdash \Delta,D} \text {RC}$$

The "meaning" of the rule is the following :

> > we can always "cancel" redundant occurrences of a formula in the antecedent or succedent of a sequent.

---

*Added*

The basic semantic definitions for *sequents* are :

> a sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ is satisfied in an interpretation if either some formula in $\Gamma$ is **not** satisfied, or some formula in $\Delta$ is satisfied

and :

> a sequent is *valid* if it is satisfied in every interpretation.

This means that we have to "read" a sequent as follows :

> $$(\gamma_1 \land \ldots \gamma_n) \rightarrow (\delta_1 \lor \ldots \delta_m)$$

where $\Gamma = \{ \gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n \}$ and $\Delta = \{ \delta_1, \ldots, \delta_m \}$.

For simplicity, assume that $\Gamma = \{ \gamma_1, \gamma_2 \}$ and $\Delta = \{ \delta_1, \delta_2 \}$.

The *semantic* definition above says that the sequent is *valid* **iff**, for every interpretation, either some formula in the *antecedent* is *false* or some formula in the *succedent* is *true*, i.e. :

> $$\vDash (\gamma_1 \land \gamma_2) \rightarrow (\delta_1 \lor \delta_2)$$

If it so, then we can add a formula $D$ whatever to the antecedent, and if the conjunction $\gamma_1 \land \gamma_2$ is *false* the new conjunction $(\gamma_1 \land \gamma_2) \land D$ will still be *false* or we can add a formula $D$ whatever to the succedent, and if the disjunction $\delta_1 \lor \delta_2$ is *true* the new disjunction $(\delta_1 \lor \delta_2) \lor D$ will still be *true*.

In both cases, **if** the *upper* sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ is *valid*, **then** also the *lower* ones : $D,\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ and $\Gamma \vdash \Delta,D$ are.

Comment: I understand some parts of your answer now, thanks to @5xum. I just have a follow up question: Why is it that we can add a formula to the succedent? Wouldn't it mean that \Gamma can prove both \Delta and D now (which doesn't seem valid because of D)?

Comment: This is a wee bit late, but the succedent is a *disjunctive list of predicates*.  $\Gamma\vdash \Delta, D$ means that *at least one from* predicate $D$ *or* the predicates in $\Delta$ can be derived from *all from* the predicates in $\Gamma$. @BernardPollo

Answer (score 2):

Given statements p and q, where p proves q, weakening means we can add any number of statements r to the left using conjunction (and, &), yet "p & r proves q" is still valid. This is the case because we know that we can prove q if p is true, and we can prove p if "p & r" is true (using conjunction elimination, or subtraction). Therefore, we can prove q if "p & r" is true, no matter what r is.

Contraction means we can add any number of statements r to the left using disjunction (or, v), yet "p proves q v r" is still valid. In this case, we know we can prove q if p is true, and "q v r" can be proven if q is true (using disjunction introduction or addition). (Don't forget that "p v true" is a tautology, meaning it's always true). Therefore, we can prove "q v r" if p is true, no matter what r is.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might help you writing better-looking posts.